# The server stun:stun.l.google.com:19302 returned an error with code=701: STUN host lookup received error

Tags: android, webrtc, stun, turn

I am facing this error while testing STUN Servers in Chrome:

> The server stun:stun.l.google.com:19302 returned an error with code=701:
>   STUN host lookup received error.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

However, when I test it in Microsoft Edge browser, it works perfectly fine. Can anyone tell what is the issue?

I am also not able to get callback  `onIceCandidate` being invoked in Android as well.

Comment: There is this discussion which is still going on with no solution... https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/1227

Answer (score 1):

The 701 error code received in `onIceCandidateError` callback is generally harmless and can be ignored. It indicates that DNS lookup failed for ipv6.

`onIceCandidate` is invoked after you set your local description. From my experience if its not getting invoked that means there is no common Codec that is supported by both peers. Look at the SDP offer and answer generated and you'll probably find that none of the Codec is common.